# Broken KDE Emoji Picker

Tags: kde, fonts, emoji

### EDIT

I do not understand what happened, or why, but it *just works* now. I've run multiple updates, so I'm thinking this was a very niche/specific incompatibility with the software setup I have that was resolved via an update somewhere along the line. The kernel has updated, as have the Nvidia drivers, so I would assume one of those is the culprit.

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.4.0-72-generic
Uptime: 6m
Packages: 2853
Shell: zsh 5.8
Resolution: 2560x1440
DE: KDE 5.68.0 / Plasma 5.18.5
WM: KWin
GTK Theme: Breeze [GTK2/3]
Icon Theme: breeze-dark
Disk: 88G / 261G (35%)
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3800X 8-Core @ 16x 3.9GHz
GPU: GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER
RAM: 3934MiB / 64290MiB
```

---

### Original

I've been racking my head over why the emoji picker in Kubuntu is so utterly broken for me and I honestly have no idea why this is like this. A lot of emojis are in the wrong place, when I click on an emoji I'll often get the the wrong one copied, and the app basically just does not function as expected across the board.

I have the Noto Color Emoji font. I have tried disabling Anti Aliasing, changing my monospace font to Noto Color Emoji (default one), and I've even tried looking for an alternative picker. I'd really just like for this *this one* to work though.

I *am* using the Nvidia drivers (not Nouveau) as the default, but I am not willing to change this as we all know how well Nvidia and "stable" go together on Linux, and it is actually stable.

This is my screenfetch in case that is important. My current theme is Layan, however changing it has no effect on the broken picker. When I *can* get an emoji search limited to around 2-3 results it is "sort of" reliable.

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.4.0-65-generic
Uptime: 39m
Packages: 2477
Shell: zsh 5.8
Resolution: 2560x1440
DE: KDE 5.68.0 / Plasma 5.18.5
WM: KWin
GTK Theme: Breeze [GTK2/3]
Icon Theme: Tela
Disk: 115G / 260G (47%)
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3800X 8-Core @ 16x 3.9GHz
GPU: GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER
RAM: 3546MiB / 64293MiB
```

Please if there is absolutely anything else that I can provide to help narrow down why the kerning is broken, and why some emojis are not properly resolving (the white rectangles), I will be more than happy to update the question with that.

[image: Screenshot of the broken picker]